# Maven cannot for life download maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.6

Tags: maven-3

Basic info:
I use embedded Maven 3.0.4 in Eclipse Juno (with JBoss Tools).

settings.xml (straight from community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users):

```
<profile>
    <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>jboss-public-repository</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>jboss-deprecated-repository</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Note: I tried also repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/jboss and repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ with same results.

What I did:
I created Maven project from scrath using artifact org.jboss.spec.archetypes jboss-javaee6-webapp. System try to download repos. Everything downloads fine except two POMs:

```
maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.6.pom
plexus-2.0.2.pom
```

I will focus on maven-plugin-descriptor, but plexus behave identically.

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project example: 
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources failed: 
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 (): 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:pom:2.0.6 from/to central (repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
No response received after 60000 -> [Help 1]
```

Requested file is not present at all in repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.0.6/ (returns 404).
I tried to go to repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.0.6/ directly in browser. File maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.6.pom is present, but after click it thinks... thinks... thinks... aaand connection reset. Note that many other POMs was downloaded from repo.maven.apache.org without problems. Only this file for some reason Just Don't Work(TM).

Other:
I am NOT behind proxy. I DID use "delete whatever.lastUpdated" trick. Even deleted entire repo to force downloading everything again. Did not work, of course.

Any ideas? Or maybe I am barking at wrong tree and some other repository must be set in settings.xml? I have impression that maven tries to download too old versions...

Answer (score 4):

Problem was solved. If someone have similiar problem to mine, he have to use **mirrors**.

In settings.xml:

```
<settings>
...
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>uk.maven.org</id>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <name>UK Central</name>
            <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
...
</settings>
```